# Trouble with Validation script showing error-div

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, show

I'm having trouble trying to make this script work.  The css changes work fine, but the #error-div does not show up.

Any ideas?

erik

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#rbSubmit').formValidator({
        scope: '#form_register',
        onError: function () {

    if ($('#input_2 input').hasClass('error-input')) { 
        $('#r2 div, #r2 input' ).css('background-color', '#C1272D').css('color', '#FFF'); 
        $("#error_div").show(); } 
    else { $('#r2 div' ).css('background-color', '#2F2F2F'); }  
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: would really appreciate the html code also.

Comment: #error-div or #error_div ? code says #error_div. you might have a spelling mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you mention #error-div (with a dash). But in your code you are using #error_div (with an underscore). That might be the problem.

Comment: Wow Wow Wow. If only OP actually posted his HTML this would have been much more apparent. Good guess though from incomplete information.